# Linked Tables in Red-Gate SQL Source Control (SSC) - Performance Nightmare?

Tags: sql, version-control, redgate

Our team is using Red-Gate SQL Source Control as our database CM tool. 
After performing a quick test to determine how linking static data affects the speed of SQL Source Control, I got the following results:

- 1st run  -- 85 seconds   (26 linked tables with 13.9MB data)
- 2nd run  -- 14 seconds!  (0 linked tables)

I started with 26 linked tables in my database. It took about 85 seconds for SQL Source Control to show changes in the "Commit Changes". After I removed all linked tables, it only took 14 seconds. Before each run, I restarted SSMS.

1. Does anyone else have any similar issues?
2. What other tools / methods other than SSC would you recommend for SQL DB CM and storing static data? (Something that is preferably as easy to setup and use across a bigger team)

Until Red Gate fixes this performance issue in linking static data, we are considering using SQL scripts to put data under source control.

Comment: Which version of SQL Source Control are you using? Have you got 3.0.9.18?

Comment: I updated SSC to 3.0.11.3531 today. I saw very little performance improvement. It takes about 70 seconds to see changes in the "Commit Changes" tab for 27 linked tables with 14.6 MB data.

Comment: We're having the same problem (SSC version 3.0.11.3531).  We attempted to add a huge lookup table (it holds geographic data and is something on the order of 6 million rows) to source control and link the static data and the performance of "commit changes" becomes completely unacceptable.  I think we're going to have to unlink the static data.

Answer (score 1):

We're running version 3.0.12.3695 and having exactly same problems. This issue was already reported on their forums and support team. If you have the 3.0.12 version running this may help you: [General performance](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=15256)